# How to print out the whole contents of a stack?

Tags: java, stack

I want to know a way to print out the contents of a whole stack in java, without popping the elements out as they need to stay in the stack. I was think of using peek but can't think of a way to move through the stack and then print them all, I can only peek at the value at the top of the stack.

Comment: do you use `java.util.Stack` or another implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's `java.util.Stack` you're talking about, it has an `iterator()` method, which you can use to iterate over its elements, for example:

```
Iterator<Integer> iterator = stack.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iterator.next());
}
```

You could also use the `.toString()` method.
For example if the stack has 1, 2, 3, 4 in it,
then `.toString()` will format it as `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

To iterate from top to bottom, you could use `stack.listIterator()` instead to iterate backward:

```
ListIterator<Integer> listIterator = stack.listIterator(stack.size());
while (listIterator.hasPrevious()) {
    System.out.println(listIterator.previous());
}
```

Comment: and if he wants to print from top to bottom?

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions come to mind. You don't have access to the non-top elements of the stack so:

1) You can print as you put things into the stack.

2) You can pop them into a temp stack and print them. then once the original stack is empty, push them all back from the temp stack to the original stack.